# 14.04 freezes on start and stalls on restart/power down

Tags: shutdown, freeze, login-screen, 14.04

About 2 out of 3 times I power on my computer, Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when loading some stage of the login (lightDM) screen. I have to manually power off my computer.

Also, when I go to restart or shutdown my computer from the menu, it just stalls on the Ubuntu screen with the four orange to white dots underneath it for all of time, or on a black screen, and I have to manually power off my computer. I thought perhaps this was an issue with the upgrade I did from 13.10 to 14.04 so I re-installed 14.04 over again from a bootable USB. Problem still persists. I am very new to Ubuntu, and don't really know what I'm doing/looking for with any kind of bug fixes, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same problem.
Sometimes, after powering my machine on, Ubuntu 14.04 frozes on login screen... After a forced reboot everything works ok. This doen't happen with 12.04 (the version I was using before upgrading).

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes I have to force re-boot multiple times. Sometimes I get past my password entry and it freezes on the transition to unity.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like issues with your graphics driver. Is this happening right after the install or after you install a proprietary driver?

I had this issue after installing a prop. driver and switching my monitor from the integrated graphics port my gpu. I know if you have an ATI driver, you are going to have to use the integrated graphics to install Ubuntu, and then install and set up the graphics drivers before switching back to your gpu. After doing `sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all` and restarting, you'll have to do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then do `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then switch the numbers on Default 1 and Default 2 that look like 00:00:00:00 and 01:00:01:00, because for some reason it automatically uses the integrated graphics as default, instead of the gpu.

Comment: I don't know what this means O_o. I haven't installed any drivers, just using the ones that come stock with Ubuntu, which is what I did when using 13.10 and had no problems.