# Acer Aspire 7750G graphics conflict with 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, acer, proprietary, aspire

So I posted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450180/14-04-freezes-on-start-and-stalls-on-restart-power-down) the other day, as I was having freeze issues with my new install of 14.04. I installed updates and after a few days the issue seems to have ceased. But what has persisted is lagging. Lagging upon text entry, upon window moving/minimizing, cursor trails, etc. I've read there may be conflicts with the graphics card that comes with this laptop, and I may need to install proprietary drivers? I have no idea what I'm doing. Is there some terminal line I can enter to see if there is a conflict? How can I tell what I need to do to fix this issue? As I said in my last post and above, I have no idea what I'm doing, so I greatly appreciate any community help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to start by identifying your hardware. Also gnome / Unity seem to be the most demanding for video cards, try k/x/lubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I too have one of the 7750G models from Acer. I too had a very similar issue, trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 where it would lock up and eventually dump kernel debug info.

My solution:

- Boot into BIOS (F2 when starting on my model)
- Change Switchable graphics to Integrated(turn off the second GPU)
- Save & Exit

Install Ubuntu! :)

You can then install fglrx for AMD drivers(if you have an AMD GPU) next time you boot Ubuntu, and after that you can turn the Switchable graphics back on!

You will also then encounter an issue with changing the brightness. Refer to [Can't adjust brightness on my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9047/cant-adjust-brightness-on-my-laptop) which has an answer that solves the issue.

P.S. I have read that to get Steam to install, you must install it before you install the fglrx driver.